# Reducing line spacing in a wrappd table cell text

Tags: tables, cell

Apologies in advance, I am a complete LaTeX beginner trying to fix a problem with an existing system. I have isolated the issue into the following test code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=10mm, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{56mm}|}
\hline\begingroup\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
This is an overlong line that should be wrapping\endgroup\\
\hline This is an overlong line that should be wrapping\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I need to reduce line spacing in the first of these cells and I can find no way of doing so.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: You have a \begingroup with no \endgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the layout you are looking for?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=10mm, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{56mm}|}
\hline
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
This is an overlong line that should be wrapping\\
\hline 
This is an overlong line that should be wrapping\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm... Not really. Perhaps my ignorance makes me ask I am a wrong question. :-) Essentially I need to find a way to ensure that a text which wraps into the a second line (guaranteed no third line!) is not going to make the whole row wider. I know I can reduce the font size, to make sure I get a single line, but unfortunately the the font becomes too small to be acceptable. Hence my (unsuccessful) attempts to reduce the gap between the two lines, having somewhat reduced the font. But standard ways of doing so (e.g. reducing \baselineskip don't seem to help).

Comment: @MikeArnautov I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Can you maybe edit your question and include a clear description of the desired result?